# Working with Graphics in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

i haven't worked with graphics until now.. so I have not much ideas about using graphics objects in flash cs6.
I want to move this character depending if the person has pressed a button and stop his movement once the button is released. I looked up on how to go about this process.. so far one thing that kept coming up was to turn my spritesheet into graphics.. but after that i couldn't really find anything on how to integrate this into actionscript. Plus when I convert an object into graphics it doesn't give me options to assign it a class name. so can somebody give me a good breakdown on what is the purpose of these graphics objects? and how should I go about making a sprite move?

Comment: Do you mean that you're creating a library symbol of the type "Graphic" and you're trying to associate it to something in ActionScript? You should be using a MovieClip instead. Graphics are purely for timeline animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregard information concerning sprite sheets. These are used as a completely different method of graphics rendering that I'm not going to cover here; for more advanced, high performance applications and games.

When you say Graphics, I am assuming that you mean you've created some drawings that you've converted to a Graphic like this:

[image]

These types of objects are used purely for timeline animation. What you want to use here is the type `MovieClip`. When you use this type, you'll be able to give the object a class name like you mentioned:

[image]

After doing this, you'll be able to refer to that library symbol in ActionScript like this:

```
var gr:MyGraphic = new MyGraphic();
addChild(gr);
```

Comment: but how do I do a sprite movement?